# Adding custom formula to Range() cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

```
    Sub test()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'keeping the screen clean

    Sheets("Data").Select



'Here is where the error is triggered.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestSheet")
        '.Range("A2:A" & Lr).Formula = "=CusVlookup(Z2,Data'!A:B,2)" <- this doesnt work either
        .Range("A2:A" & Lr) = "=CusVlookup(Z2,Data'!A:B,2)"
    End With

    End Sub


Function CusVlookup(lookupval, LookupRange As Range, indexcol As Long)
    Dim x As Range
    Dim Result As String
    Result = ""
    For Each x In LookupRange
        If x = lookupval Then
            Result = Result & "," & x.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
        End If
    Next x
    CusVlookup = Result
End Function
```

I've tried using the regular Vlookup and works just fine but if I try to use this custom function it triggers the error. By the way I need to get the multiple matches "vlookups" into one cell separated by comma.(I added the goal just in case you know a better/faster way to do the same.)

whats wrong with the code?

> Error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Should be `Data!` - not the extra quote.

Comment: @SJR If the worksheet name has a single space character following the word *Data*, then the single quote is needed.

Comment: @SJR: awesome! not sure how it got there! thank you!

Comment: Where is `Lr` defined?